# How to find files in ruby which were edited in some time interval?

Tags: ruby, unix

How to find files in a directory which were edited in last n minutes?

In unix which is `-mmin -60`.

In `host`

`ruby /home/ava/test` works fine!

```
Net::SSH.start('host', 'ava') do |ssh|
 `ruby /home/ava/test`
end
```

gives `ruby: No such file or directory -- /home/ava/test (LoadError)`

Comment: We'd like to see code you've written so we can correct or expand on it. `-mmin -60` applies to `find` at the command-line. Have you looked for the equivalent in Ruby's File or File::Stat classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get a list of files using `Dir.[]`, and use `File.mtime` on each one to filter them:

```
Dir["*"].select { |fname| File.mtime(fname) > (Time.now - 60) }
```

Comment: this is not returning me the correct results since Time.now is a Time object and minus 60 does not do what I want which is subtract 60 minutes from the current time.

Comment: Yes, the number you subtract from Time.now is in seconds, so `Time.now - 3600` should work too.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that Ruby isn't control on the remote system you connect to, instead, the shell on that system is, and you're merely able to issue commands, as if you'd ssh'd into your own local system. Ruby's built-in commands, like `Dir.chdir` only apply locally, not to the remote session.

Your best bet is to write a script you execute that resides on that system, otherwise the task of executing commands becomes more difficult and you'll need to anticipate prompts and possibly various responses from commands on that system as your code executes things.

The Net::SSH gem includes examples showing how to issue remote commands; You need to remember that once you've connected you're issuing commands to the shell, not to Ruby.

---

```
Net::SSH.start('host', 'ava') do |ssh|
 `ruby /home/ava/test`
end
```

> gives ruby: No such file or directory -- /home/ava/test (LoadError)

The best way to diagnose this is to start by SSHing to your own local box and executing the code locally, or using surrogate code that only echoes the commands you'd be using in real life on the other machine. Then you can test to see if the actions would be called.

Instead of:

```
ruby /home/ava/test
```

issue a command like:

```
ls -al /home/ava
```

first, to see what files are visible.

Follow that with something like:

```
ruby -pe '%x(ls /home/ava)'
```

to see if Ruby is found and it can execute that command in the path.

Dealing with remote systems isn't the same as running scripts locally. Your environment can be different, meaning your PATH or variables you expect might not be the same.